# How to min_max_scale test data by group, using the grouped min max of train data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tensorflow, scikit-learn

For example, the dataset is like:

| Group | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| 1 | 0.7 | 0.34 | 0.67 |
| 2 | 0.3 | 0.1 | 0.5 |
| 2 | 0.54 | 0.6 | 0.2 |

I want to use the min and max values of every column of the training dataset to scale the test data for each column separately, which also have a similar structure. THANK YOU!

Comment: Seems like a straight application of a formula. have you tried doing it?

Comment: @rafaelc Could you please explain more?

Comment: Min-max normalization is pretty standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling#Rescaling_(min-max_normalization) . Take the min/max from the train set, and just add/subtract/divide as the formula.

Comment: Yes. But I have no idea how to implement this when group is needed...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this working as follows ;

```
import tensorflow as tf 

import pandas as pd

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler as scaler

df = pd.DataFrame([[0.1,0.2,0.3],[0.7,0.34,0.67],[0.3,0.1,0.5],[0.54,0.6,0.2]],columns=['A','B','C'])

df
```

Output:

```
    A   B   C
0   0.10    0.20    0.30
1   0.70    0.34    0.67
2   0.30    0.10    0.50
3   0.54    0.60    0.20


def transform(df):
  scaler.fit(df)
  return scaler.transform(df)
df
```

Output :

```
    A   B   C
0   0.10    0.20    0.30
1   0.70    0.34    0.67
2   0.30    0.10    0.50
3   0.54    0.60    0.20
```

The dataset is already between the range {0,1} .

MinMaxScaler will convert each value to the range 0-1 .

Hence with a different input data, the values will reflect accordingly.